# How to place circles in between two parentheses on a line segment?

Tags: tikz-pgf, brackets, line

I need to place a circle in between two parentheses on a line segment. I know how to draw multiple circles on a line segment within parentheses. I have tried the following code:

```
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
{\draw (-2,0) -- (7,0);
$\bf{\bigg(}$ (0,9);
$\bf{\big(}$ (0.5,0); \hspace{0.25cm} \filldraw [blue] (0.75,0) circle (2.5pt); $\bf{\big)}$ (1.0,0);
$\bf{\big(}$ (1.0,0); \hspace{0.25cm} \filldraw [blue] (1.25,0) circle (2.5pt); $\bf{\big)}$ (1.5,0);
$\bf{\big(}$ (1.5,0); \hspace{0.25cm} \filldraw [blue] (1.75,0) circle (2.5pt); $\bf{\big)}$ (2.0,0);
$\bf{\big(}$ (2.0,0); \hspace{0.25cm} \filldraw [blue] (2.25,0) circle (2.5pt); $\bf{\big)}$ (2.5,0);
\hspace{5.5cm} $\bf{\bigg)}$ (9,0);}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Edit: The second parenthesis ")" and the third parenthesis "(" should be in one point and similarly for others.

[image: This is what I exactly want.]

Comment: you probably need to use nodes to achieve that (even if it's not really clear what you want). And your snippet of code is not compilable, please read how to ask a question with a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: Unrelated comment: `\bf` has been deprecated since the 90s I think ,so I suggest stop using it. The modern replacement is `\bfseries`. And `\bfseries`/`\bf` are not macros that take arguments. To limit their effect, use `{\bfseries foo}`. Alternatively use `\textbf{foo}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe that's what you're looking for:

[image: circles in parentheses]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}

\newcommand{\parentcirc}[1]%
    {
    \filldraw [blue] (#1,0) circle (2.5pt) node[left,black] {$\bigg($} node[right,black] {$\bigg)$};
    }
\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (-2,0) -- (7,0);
        \foreach \i in {-1,0,1,3,5,6}
            {
            \parentcirc{\i}
            }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### EDIT

In order to correspond to the picture you added in your question, here's an edit that you could have done yourself, by fine tuning the nodes placement.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}

\newcommand{\parentcirc}[1]%
    {
    \filldraw [blue] (#1,0) circle (2.5pt) node[left,black] {$\big($} node[right,black] {$\big)$};
    }
\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (-2,0) -- (7.25,0);
        \foreach \i in {-1,-0.55,...,6.5}
            {
            \parentcirc{\i}
            }
        \path (-1.5,0) node {$\bigg($} (6.7,0) node {$\bigg)$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Whichs gives the following:

[image: whatever you need]

Comment: Thanks for this. Can we have the 2nd and 3rd parenthesis at one point?

Comment: Thanks a lot for this beauty. I have managed to do so by just using `\hspace{-0.4truecm}` in the preamble (newcommand). Is there any other command for this?

Comment: I suggest you don't use `\hspace` here because it's irrelevant. Each node can be placed with a fine tuning. I don't really understand what you mean by *2nd and 3rd parenthesis at one point* but here I used a `foreach` loop to place several items on the line, and you can place them wherever you want, for example with `\parentcirc{2.53}` which would place the blue circle at `(2.53,0)`.

Comment: Can you please have a look at the image that I have recently added in the question?

Comment: I edited my answer too.

Comment: That's cool. Thanks a lot Professor. This is exactly what I want. 

Comment: Cool. Feel free to accept the answer to let people know that you already get what you needed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134341/discussion-between-pinaki-prasad-kar-and-sebglav).